# Java round decimal numbers

Tags: java, decimal, rounding

I am trying to get a discount of an amount given

lets say: amount = "1.2" and discountPercentage = "17.3"

### Code:

```
orig = Double.parseDouble("amount");
discount = orig*(discountPercentage/100);
discount = Math.round(discount);

discountedprice =  orig - discount;
```

On the code above: when I round the discount using Math.round(0.2076) i am getting Zero(0) result.

What I want to happen is like this:

0.2076 = should get 0.21 when rounded up

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
float round(float f,float prec)
{
    return (float) (Math.floor(f*(1.0f/prec) + 0.5)/(1.0f/prec));
}
```

**use**

```
round(0.2076f,0.01f)
```

**result**

```
0.21
```

Comment: care to explain the down vote? it works perfectly

Comment: Almost perfectly, 0.01f cannot be represented exactly and introduces an error. Use 100 instead as this can be represented exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
discount *= 100;
discount = Math.round(discount);
discount /= 100;
...
```

Comment: [Refutation here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12684082/207421).

Comment: Refutation, refuted here. Using Math.round for this range of `double` as no errors http://ideone.com/BVCHh3

Answer (score 0):

Error:

```
orig = Double.parseDouble("amount");
```

does not use the variable, but is a string with the content a-m-o-u-n-t.

```
String amount = "1.2";
double orig = Double.parseDouble(amount);
double discount = orig*(discountPercentage/100);
discount = Math.round(discount);
```

However be warned, that a `double` value can only be an approximation of a decimal number, as it is a sum of powers of 2; 0.2 being 2<sup>-3</sup> ... Hence 100 * 0.01 is not precisely equal to 1.0.

For financial software it is better to use BigDecimal, which however is more circumstantial though. For a taste:

```
BigBecimal amount = new BigDecimal("1.20"); // Precision of 2 decimals.
BigDecimal discount = amount.multiply(discountPercentage.movePointLeft(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

your code will throw a NumberFormatException because of

```
orig = Double.parseDouble("amount");
```

You are trying to parse a number from the acutal String "amount".
If you already have the amount variable initalized, you should use that variable (remove the quotes in the parseDouble method.
E.g.

```
    String amount = "7.0";
    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(amount));
```

Also the types of your variables are not clear: discount, discountPercentage, discountedPrice.
Based on the code you provided in your question, a lot is not clear and therefore could be part of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Float` or `Double` for money calculations. Use `BigDecimal` instead as e.g. stated [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13) or [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/working-money-java).

Some code:

```
final BigDecimal orig = new BigDecimal(1.2);
final BigDecimal discountPercentage = new BigDecimal(0.173);
final BigDecimal discount = orig.multiply(discountPercentage);
System.out.println("discount = " + discount.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
```

Prints:

> discount = 0.21

Comment: I agree, never use `Float`, or `Double` or `float`, but you can use `BigDecimal`, `double` with rounding and `long` with fixed precision.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I should have added a link to your post as well: http://vanillajava.blogspot.ch/2011/08/double-your-money-again.html. However I think for the normal use `BigDecimal` is the better solution.

Comment: You can argue either way in terms of technology, but really what matters is what do you feel is the more error prone.  Many prefer the explicit scale & rounding functions and for them this produces less errors in code.